# how to fix error (ValueError: Expected object or value) when using read_json

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('publicextract.charity.json')
csvData = df.to_csv('new.csv')
```

I am trying to open a json file and save it to a CSV. i am getting this error from the read_json

**Error** - loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Expected object or value

This is what the json data looks like for example from charity file name - https://register-of-charities.charitycommission.gov.uk/register/full-register-download

```
[{"date_of_extract":"2022-10-15T00:00:00","organisation_number":1,"registered_charity_number":200027,"linked_charity_number":1,"charity_name":"POTTERNE MISSION ROOM AND TRUST","charity_type":null,"charity_registration_status":"Removed","date_of_registration":"1962-05-17T00:00:00","date_of_removal":"2014-04-16T00:00:00","charity_reporting_status":null,"latest_acc_fin_period_start_date":null,"latest_acc_fin_period_end_date":null,"latest_income":null,"latest_expenditure":null,"charity_contact_address1":null,"charity_contact_address2":null,"charity_contact_address3":null,"charity_contact_address4":null,"charity_contact_address5":null,"charity_contact_postcode":null,"charity_contact_phone":null,"charity_contact_email":null,"charity_contact_web":null,"charity_company_registration_number":null,"charity_insolvent":false,"charity_in_administration":false,"charity_previously_excepted":null,"charity_is_cdf_or_cif":null,"charity_is_cio":null,"cio_is_dissolved":null,"date_cio_dissolution_notice":null,"charity_activities":null,"charity_gift_aid":null,"charity_has_land":null}
,{"date_of_extract":"2022-10-15T00:00:00","organisation_number":2,"registered_charity_number":200027,"linked_charity_number":2,"charity_name":"HITCHAM FREE CHURCH","charity_type":null,"charity_registration_status":"Registered","date_of_registration":"1962-05-17T00:00:00","date_of_removal":null,"charity_reporting_status":null,"latest_acc_fin_period_start_date":null,"latest_acc_fin_period_end_date":null,"latest_income":null,"latest_expenditure":null,"charity_contact_address1":null,"charity_contact_address2":null,"charity_contact_address3":null....}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create dataframe directly like this

```
import json
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(open("file.json").read()))
df

#output looks like this
       date_of_extract  organisation_number  registered_charity_number  
0  2022-10-15T00:00:00                    1                     200027   
1  2022-10-15T00:00:00                    2                     200027
```